# View Table Format with a group by

Tags: views

Is there a way to create a group by in a table views.

Here is how I would like that the group by looks like

[image]

Comment: finally, do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_table_rowspan) is a module that does exactly the same as you want.

From Module page.

> > Create a new view (eg: a list of node).
> >     Set format Table Rowspan for this view.
> >     Add some field to this view.
> >     Group field that has same value.
> >     Check option "Merge rows in group".

Click on settings and group by your results by `Principal`, `Guest`, `Email Member`, `Non Email Member`. This module will render your table in exactly the same format you want.

Comment: I never hear about this module, I will test it, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) to achieve this.

> The Views Merge Rows module provides a way to combine rows with the
>   same content in the specified fields.

I use this module in a project and it works fine.